# How can we use artificial neural networks to find similar documents?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, word-embedding

How can we use ANN to find some similar documents? I know its a silly question, but I am new to this NLP field.
I have made a model using kNN and bag-of-words approach to solve my problem. Using that I can get n number of documents (along with their closeness) that are somewhat similar to the input, but now I want to implement the same using ANN and I am not getting any idea.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Why do you want to use ANN? What is the size of your data? It is for educational purpose that you want to explore multiple ways of solving the problem? Or is it a real professional problem? If it's latter why do you want to move away from kNN and not try and increase accuracy of kNN itself?

Comment: The main reason I want to do this with ANN is because using kNN with bag of word will not consider the word order. By using n-gram we can somehow solve this issue but it is not as much effective as RNN with LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "word embeddings" - technique, that presents words in the dense vector representation. To find similar documents as the vectors, you can simply use [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity).

An example how to build [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec) model using TensorFlow. One more example how to use [embeddings layer](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) from Keras.

Answer (score 0):

The way to obtain embeddings for your language is either [training them yourself on your corpus of choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573873/how-to-train-word2vec-on-very-large-datasets) (large enough - e.g. wikipedia) or downloading the trained embeddings (for python there are plenty of sources for embeddings trained or loadable with [`gensim`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) module - which is a de facto standard for Python word2vec).

You can also use [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) (using [`glove-python`](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python)) or [FastText](https://fasttext.cc/) word embeddings.

If you are interested you can find more [detailed descriptions of embeddings with code examples and source papers](https://github.com/Hironsan/awesome-embedding-models).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10685.pdf that gives you a overall idea.
check this link for more references https://github.com/Hironsan/awesome-embedding-models